# Tangent to $x^4+y^4=1$

Tags: analysis

Given the curve $$K=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^4+y^4=1, x\ge 0, y\ge 0\}.$$

How can I find the tangent on $K$ at $\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{15^{1/4}}{2}\right)$?

Is it right if I consider the function $f(x)=(1-x^4)^{1/4}$ and calculate the tangent of $f$ in $\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{2},f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$?

Comment: $y= (1- x^4)^{1/4}$ only gives part of the graph.  However, here, where y is positive, that is the right part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

note that we get  from $$x^4+y^4=1$$ by differentiation with respect to $x$:
$$4x^3+4y^3y'=0$$ thus $$y'=-\frac{x^3}{y^3}$$
can you go on?
plug in the coordinates of the given Point we will get the slope of our Tangent line
$$y'=-\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3}{\left(\frac{15^{1/4}}{2}\right)^3}$$
can you compute this term?
with your way by defining $$f(x)=(1-x^4)^{1/4}$$ you will get
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{4}(1-x^4)^{-3/4}(-4x^3)$$ insert the $x$ coordinate and compare the slopes, it must be the same

Comment: No not really, I don't know what I should do next :/

Comment: Alright! Thank you very much :) Would my discribed way work as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the standard equation of a circle to be $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$, then the center is at $C(h,k)$, hence, when $h$ and $k$ equal $0$, the center is at $C(0,0)$. Given this, you can work out what the gradient is from $(0,0)$ to $\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{15^{1/4}}{2}\right)$ using the $\displaystyle m=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}$ formula.

Once this is done, using the negative reciprocal (i.e. $-\frac{1}{m}$) of the gradient will give the gradient of the tangent (as targents and radii are are perpendicular to each other)

Finally, using the $-\frac{1}{m}(x-x_1)=y-y_1$ formula (using $\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{15^{1/4}}{2}\right)$ as the $x_1$ and $y_1$ values, should yield the equation of the tangent.

This is a more basic way of approaching the issue, and doesn't rely so much on calculus, but rather just pre-calculus algebra.